# Does a Bitcoin qr code become invalid after 1 Year?

Tags: qrcode, wallet-development

I have been trying to figure out if there exist a software which preserves a BTC QR code for more than one year.

Comment: Note: bitcoin addresses (encoded into QR code or not) may not expire, but if you are sending BTC to someone, you should still ask for a new address each time.

Answer (score 3):

> Does a Bitcoin qr code become invalid after 1 Year?

Generally no. A Bitcoin QR code encodes a Bitcoin address. These addresses are valid forever - in the sense that valid Bitcoin transactions can be created which pay to those addresses. So long as someone still knows the original private key (or master private key) for the address, any money sent using that QR code in 5 10 or 100 years time, can still be used.